# -source code of chromium embedded framework

Tags: chromium, chromium-embedded

How to download the latest chromium embedded framework source code (chromium embedded framework 3) ?
https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is project's page. Read https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/BranchesAndBuilding page, it describes source repository structure and contains build instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Project is moved to bitbucket. Read the branching and building page, and use automate-git.py script as documented.